# PyCharm: Failed to install PyGObject in Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

[image]

I tried to do many ways like installing visual studio c++ and different version of python from version 3.6 - 3.4 but still have an error like the image shown.

Can anyone help me guys?